# Use a function outside ngOnInit() inside ngOnInit()

Tags: javascript, angular, api, openlayers

I'm programming a map with [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) (4.6.5) in [Angular](https://angular.io/) (6). I use also a french [API](https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/api) provided by the french government to create requests and return GeoJSON files.

I have already programmed a map with static GeoJSON files like this :

```
this.parkingLayer = new VectorSource({
  url: '.../file.geojson',
  format: new GeoJSON()
});

this.vectorLayer_parking = new VectorLayer({
  source: this.parkingLayer
});
```

And now I want to use this API and create requests dynamically !
I have created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxqjux) to illustrate my question.

My problem is I have created a getLocation() function outside the ngOnInit() (that was mandatory) and now I want to use the `const url = 'https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=${Longitude}&lat=${Latitude}'` in the `this.locationLayer` ! How can I do that ? The goal being to place the points on the map (according to the generated GeoJSON file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle http request with the Angular HttpClient.

1. First import HttpClientModule in your app.module

   ```
   import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

   @NgModule({
     imports: [
       ...,
       HttpClientModule
     ],
      ...
   })
   ```
2. In your app.component, fetch the information from server

   ```
   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {this.getLocation();}

   getLocation(): void{
       if (navigator.geolocation) {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position)=>{
               const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
               const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
               this.callApi(longitude, latitude).subscribe(n => {
                   console.log(n);
                   //here you can add the geometry to a vector source
               });
           });
       } else {
           console.log("No support for geolocation")
       }
   }

   callApi(Longitude: number, Latitude: number): Observable<any> {
       const url = `https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=${Longitude}&lat=${Latitude}`;    
       return this.http.get(url)
   }
   ```
3. After use openlayers to create a VectorSource and once the server information is fetch add the geometry on the source

Comment: Thank you for your answer, with the code that you gave me the `getLocation` function is executed at the start of the page. Is there a way to launch this function only when I click on the button ? I have updated my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxqjux). I didn't understand how can I place my vectorSource ...

Comment: Of course, your function is called into the constructor, just remove it.